# Trigger power automate workflow on new teams message to specific channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

Is there a way to start a workflow within power automate when a new message is posted to a specific channel? I want to trigger an additional notification via email after a message is posted.

Comment: With all due respect, have you had a look at the triggers available for Microsoft teams?